# Starting with a sorted array, determine the number of occurrences of a value. [Interview Prep]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I recently interviewed for a Software Engineering position and wanted to go over the question and solution that I arrived at.

Given a sorted array of numbers (possibly containing duplicates), determine the number of times that a value appears in the list.

i.e. if `array = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,7]`, how many 3s are in the list

Comment: The first response below?

Answer (score 7):

The naive approach would use a for-loop to iterate through the entire list and increment a counter each time the value was found. For example

```
def naiveCount(numbers, key):
    count = 0
    for n in numbers:
        if n == key:
            count += 1
    return count
```

We acknowledge that since the algorithm is going through each value in the array, it has complexity `O(n)`. Then they ask... can you do better?

---

So we start by using clues toward a better solution. We are given a **sorted** array, which opens us up to some searching algorithms that may be better than `O(n)`, perhaps the binary search.

So we can binary search our list and get the index of the first occurrence of the key at cost `O(logn)`. From there, we can walk forward through the array and increment a counter until we find a value that's not equal to the key. If there are `k` occurrences of the key, we end with a complexity of `O(logn + k)`.

An example of this algorithm includes a binary search, and a counter as follows:

```
def binary_search(arr, key, low, high):
    if high >= low:
        middle = (low + high)/2
        if (middle == 0 or key > arr[middle -1]) and arr[middle] == key:
            return middle
        elif key > arr[middle]:
            return binary_search(arr, key, middle + 1, high)
        else:
            return binary_search(arr, key, low, middle - 1)
    return None

def countAfterSearching(numbers, key):
    count = 0
    firstIndex = binary_search(numbers, key, 0, len(numbers) - 1)
    if firstIndex == None:
        return count
    else:
        for n in numbers[firstIndex:len(numbers)]:
            if n > key:
                return count
            else:
                count += 1
```

The interviewer will hopefully be impressed with your ability to decide on the binary search, but will ask "can you do better?"

---

We already know that the binary search finds the first occurrence index at cost `O(logn)`. We should be able to use a binary search the find the last occurrence's index. Subtracting the two positions and adding 1 will reveal the number of occurrences.

For example:

```
def binary_search_first(arr, key, low, high):
    if high >= low:
        middle = (low + high)/2
        if (middle == 0 or key > arr[middle -1]) and arr[middle] == key:
            return middle
        elif key > arr[middle]:
            return first(arr, key, middle + 1, high)
        else:
            return first(arr, key, low, middle - 1)
    return None

def binary_search_last(arr, key, low, high):
    if high >= low:
        middle = (low + high) / 2
        if (middle == len(arr) - 1 or key < arr[middle + 1]) and arr[middle] == key:
            return middle
        elif(key < arr[middle]):
            return last(arr, key, low, middle - 1)
        else:
            return last(arr, key, middle + 1, high)
    return None

def count(arr, key):
    rightmost = binary_search_last(arr, key, 0, len(arr)-1)
    leftmost = binary_search_first(arr, key, 0, len(arr)-1)
    return rightmost - leftmost + 1
```

This algorithm operates with complexity O(logn), which is better than the 2 proposed options.

Comment: I agree that this might not be the most optimized solution. This type of question is prevalent in an interview type setting where you're being tested on your knowledge of time complexities and the ability to build on your own solutions.

Answer (score 2):

A really simple way of doing it would be to do the following:

```
>> array.count(3)

3
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, python's list.count(key) function runs in `O(n)` time. For something more robust and built-in, one should take a look at the Counter object in the Collection class.

Comment: @Neurax your comment makes no sense. ``list.count()`` is the fastest O(n) approach and only depends on equality being defined. It does exactly what you asked for. In contrast, ``collections.Counter()`` does a lot more work (still O(n) though) and counts everything (not what you asked for). It is "less robust" in that it requires both hashability and equality.  It also is more memory intensive. Further, in another comment, you added the somewhat bogus requirement that the standard library not be used.

Answer (score -1):

The [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) makes short work of this problem:

```
>>> from bisect import *
>>> array = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,7]
>>> bisect_right(array, 3) - bisect_left(array, 3)
3
```

Comment: It's not uncommon to find yourself in a programming environment (whiteboard, paper, limited interpreter) that prevents the use of external libraries. I agree that bisect is a phenomenal tool for this type of problem, and should certainly be favored if available.

Comment: Again, this wasn't available in the IDE that I was being tested through. The interviewer was interested in seeing the candidate build the raw solution, not source the best available library that boils down to a line or two. Like I said, I agree bisect is a useful and proper solution. If you were in my position, you would have been scrutinized for not being able to write the bisection methods. Nothing against you, just situational.. Something interviewers should be wary of.

Comment: I did post code and provided ample effort. Your comment to my response was "I had to give +1 for sheer effort"